# XML String to XML by XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to convert XMLString data to XML through xslt.
Below is the input i.e. XMLString:-

Input:-

```
&lt;Inputs&gt;&lt;field name="Call_ID"&gt;MZ_CMI_AG_04082017_117&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field name="PeopleRecordID"&gt;PPL00000000001&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field name="CTN"&gt;1&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field name="ContactName"&gt;IMIS_LoadTest1&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field name="Notes" Local_Lang="Spanish" Destination_Local="Detailed_Description_Local" Destination_Eng="Detailed_Description_English"&gt;Mr. and Mrs. Dursley, of num.&#xD;
　　At half past eight, Mr. Parsley picked up his briefcase, pecked Mrs. Dursley on the cheek, and tried to kiss Dudley good-bye but missed, because Dudley was now having a tantrum and throwing his cereal at the walls. "Little tyke," chortled Mr. Parsley as he left the house. He got into his car and backed out of number four's drive. &#xD;
　he sign; cats couldn't read ted Mr. Parsley as he left the house. He got into his car and backed out of number four's drive. &#xD;
　　 to get that day.&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field name="Summary" Local_Lang="Spanish" Destination_Local="Description_Local" Destination_Eng="Description_English"&gt;This is dummy data dummy data for test&lt;/field&gt;&lt;/Inputs&gt;
```

Can you please help me with this

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the input you have given, let's put it in a root element (`<Root></Root>`)

**E.g.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    &lt;Inputs&gt;&lt;field
    name="Call_ID"&gt;MZ_CMI_AG_04082017_117&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field
    name="PeopleRecordID"&gt;PPL00000000001&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field
    name="CTN"&gt;1&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field
    name="ContactName"&gt;IMIS_LoadTest1&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field
    name="Notes" Local_Lang="Spanish"
    Destination_Local="Detailed_Description_Local"
    Destination_Eng="Detailed_Description_English"&gt;Mr. and Mrs. Dursley,
    of num.&#xD;
    At half past eight, Mr. Parsley picked up his briefcase, pecked Mrs.
    Dursley on the cheek, and tried to kiss Dudley good-bye but missed,
    because Dudley was now having a tantrum and throwing his cereal at the
    walls. "Little tyke," chortled Mr. Parsley as he left the house. He got
    into his car and backed out of number four's drive. &#xD;
    he sign; cats couldn't read ted Mr. Parsley as he left the house. He got
    into his car and backed out of number four's drive. &#xD;
    to get that day.&lt;/field&gt;&lt;field name="Summary"
    Local_Lang="Spanish" Destination_Local="Description_Local"
    Destination_Eng="Description_English"&gt;This is dummy data dummy data
    for test&lt;/field&gt;&lt;/Inputs&gt; 
</Root>
```

If above is the right assumption of your input file, you can transform it into an XML using xslt as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Find the transformation [here](http://xsltransform.net/93wkLHP)