# Inserting XML String into XSLT between XSLT templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a problem on inserting XML strings into the XSLT I have. Particularly, I have a sample XML string here:

```
<md:People>
<md:Job>
<md:JobFunction>Actor</md:JobFunction>
<md:BillingBlockOrder>1</md:BillingBlockOrder>
</md:Job>
<md:Name>
<md:DisplayName language="en-US">Vice Ganda</md:DisplayName>
</md:Name>
</md:People>
```

and I want to insert it into the XSLT I have (see `<!-- INSERT "People" Metadata XML STRING HERE -->`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core" exclude-result-prefixes='soa' version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="basicContentID"><xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='basicContentID']/text()"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="movieTitle"><xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='movieTitle']/text()"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="releaseYear"><xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='releaseYear']/text()"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="releaseDate"><xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='releaseDate']/text()"/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">

<mdmec:CoreMetadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:md="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.6/md" xmlns:mdmec="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/mdmec/v2.6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/mdmec/v2.6/mdmec-v2.6.xsd">

<mdmec:Basic ContentID="{/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='basicContentID']/text()}">

<md:LocalizedInfo language="{/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='metadataLanguage']/text()}">

<md:TitleDisplayUnlimited><xsl:value-of select="$movieTitle"/></md:TitleDisplayUnlimited>

</md:LocalizedInfo>

<!-- INSERT "People" Metadata XML STRING HERE -->

</mdmec:Basic>

<md:ReleaseYear><xsl:value-of select="$releaseYear"/></md:ReleaseYear>
<md:ReleaseDate><xsl:value-of select="$releaseDate"/></md:ReleaseDate>
</mdmec:CoreMetadata>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...to have an XML output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<mdmec:CoreMetadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:md="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.6/md" xmlns:mdmec="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/mdmec/v2.6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/mdmec/v2.6/mdmec-v2.6.xsd">

<mdmec:Basic ContentID="md:cid:org:abs_cbn:StarCinema-BeautyAndTheBestie2015">

<md:LocalizedInfo language="en-US">

<md:TitleDisplayUnlimited>Beauty and The Bestie</md:TitleDisplayUnlimited>

</md:LocalizedInfo>
 
<!-- Where "People" Metadata should be appearing -->
<md:People>
<md:Job>
<md:JobFunction>Actor</md:JobFunction>
<md:BillingBlockOrder>1</md:BillingBlockOrder>
</md:Job>
<md:Name>
<md:DisplayName language="en-US">Vice Ganda</md:DisplayName>
</md:Name>
</md:People>

</mdmec:Basic>

<md:ReleaseYear><xsl:value-of select="$releaseYear"/></md:ReleaseYear>
<md:ReleaseDate><xsl:value-of select="$releaseDate"/></md:ReleaseDate>

</mdmec:CoreMetadata>
```

Basically, the XML string I wanted to insert is in between the `<mdmec:basic>` code, and defining an xslt template in-between the root is not allowed. How can I go through this?

Thanks for all your help in advance!

---

EDIT: I tried to reproduce the sample from this thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535142/xml-string-to-xml-by-xslt] by re-creating the XML string I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>    
<Root>
    <md:People>
    <md:Job>
    <md:JobFunction>Actor</md:JobFunction>
    <md:BillingBlockOrder>1</md:BillingBlockOrder>
    </md:Job>
    <md:Name>
    <md:DisplayName language="en-US">Vice Ganda</md:DisplayName>
    </md:Name>
    </md:People>
 </Root>
```

...and inserted into the XSLT I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core" exclude-result-prefixes='soa' version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="basicContentID"><xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='basicContentID']/text()"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="movieTitle"><xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='movieTitle']/text()"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="releaseYear"><xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='releaseYear']/text()"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="releaseDate"><xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='releaseDate']/text()"/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<mdmec:CoreMetadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:md="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.6/md" xmlns:mdmec="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/mdmec/v2.6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/mdmec/v2.6/mdmec-v2.6.xsd">

<mdmec:Basic ContentID="{/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='basicContentID']/text()}">

<md:LocalizedInfo language="{/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[@name='metadataLanguage']/text()}">

<md:TitleDisplayUnlimited><xsl:value-of select="$movieTitle"/></md:TitleDisplayUnlimited>

</md:LocalizedInfo>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>

</mdmec:Basic>

<md:ReleaseYear><xsl:value-of select="$releaseYear"/></md:ReleaseYear>
<md:ReleaseDate><xsl:value-of select="$releaseDate"/></md:ReleaseDate>
</mdmec:CoreMetadata>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It appears to have an error: **'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'mdmec:Basic' element**

Comment: Please adit your question and show an example input. Reducing the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem would also be helpful - see: [mcve].

Comment: What does "XML string" mean exactly? Normally XSLT 1 takes an XML input document you process as a node in XSLT so you could simply use `xsl:copy-of` on that  document node or its root element.

Comment: I have an XML string, which is an example of the first code above, that will pass thru the XSLT that I have. Primarily, I looked into some samples of inserting XML strings into XSL, however, it calls for another `<xsl:template>` code that is referenced to the XML string. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535142/xml-string-to-xml-by-xslt]

I tried to reference the XML string using the sample on the link into the template, but it appears that the <mdmec:basic> appears below the referenced XML string.

Comment: I already edited the OP above to include the sample I referenced from the thread available. Hope it helps to understand.

Comment: I still don't see the XML input.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, I am actually using a software that transforms XML using the XSLT. What the software does is, I created a string within the software, which happens to be an XML string (sample above), and with the XSLT sample I have, I don't know how to transform the string into the XML, without the codes being altered by special characters _&gt;_ and _&lt;_

Comment: I am afraid I have no clue what you mean by that. Please formulate your question in terms of input, current XSLT and expected output.

Answer (score -2):

If you manage to pass the XML string into your XSL transformation as a parameter, you can output it with [escaping disabled](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#disable-output-escaping):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
<xsl:param name="xmlstring"/>
...
</md:LocalizedInfo>
<!-- INSERT "People" Metadata XML STRING HERE -->
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlstring" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</mdmec:Basic>
...
```